# Can I migrate a single disk from a datastore to another with "disks consolidation is needed" on VM?

Tags: migration, datastore, consolidation

I have a VMware's VM with configuration issue "Disks consolidation is needed" but Consolidation fail because datastore is full.
In this situation, Can I migrate a single disk from this full datastore to another (with empty space)? Or is it blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VCSA is up and ok and I can migrate disk in this situation.